# I am trying to set the z-index for an image but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I am trying to set the z-index for an image, but it's not working. Actually, the position is absolute and also, I've checked the parents z-indexes with this code to be sure that z-index is none.

```
var el = document.getElementById("bear-moving"); // or use $0 in chrome;
do {
    var styles = window.getComputedStyle(el);
    console.log(styles.zIndex);
} while(el.parentElement && (el = el.parentElement));
```

My image is moving according to the scroll and it needs to be centered. If I set the z-index, it will work only before it starts to move.

This code represents the JS to move the image.

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-element-192d237');
var image1 = document.getElementById('bear-moving');
var index = 0;
document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {

    div = document.querySelector(".elementor-element-192d237");
  if(parseInt(div.getBoundingClientRect().top)-300 < 0 && parseInt(div.getBoundingClientRect().bottom)>430) {
      var style_top = 0;
    while (style_top<window.innerHeight/2-div.getBoundingClientRect().top-25) {
        style_top = style_top+5;
        image1.style.top = style_top + 'px';
    }

  }
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide a minimal example

Comment: It looks like u don't set the z-index on the img, so there is a big chance u don't find the correct DOM element. That is a quick guess without seeing the actual code where u try to set the z-index. Could u post a link with a codepen?

Comment: It's 2 different examples. First, without z-index. In the second image the z-index is already set. I can't provide an example because it's an entire page, but I can give you the link where you can see that even if you set z-index from developer console, nothing happens. https://ayro.ro/servicii/#dezvoltare-aplicatii-web

Comment: Hi, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you put relevant code into your question.

Comment: I'm using Elementor from Wordpress, so it's not a custom code. I can edit the css, add some javascript, but html code is written by Elementor, as you see in the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying to set the z-index and guessing what's the problem, I figured out that it is a background transparent image...